# Handling cancellations for iOS In-App-Purchase recurring subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've been looking for a solution for hours, but I haven't found it yet.

I have a freemium app, where you can buy 3 month plans via iOS IAP, or via Stripe.

When a customer buys via stripe and their card fails, or when they cancel the subscription, my app receives a webhook and I can mark that customer as delinquent. This way I can report that customer as lost, and take actions to reengage with them.

However, with iOS I don't seem to have this possibility. One solution for this would be to keep a marker in my database for the `start_date` and `renewal_date` of that subscription, and mark them as lost only when they've failed a payment.

That'd be quite inconvenient, and I was wondering if there's a better way to validate with iTunes connect whether a user cancelled.